# Read-in df from csv before launching main app | Dash

Tags: bootstrap-modal, plotly-dash

I am trying to get my first dashboard with python dash running.
The whole thing is very similar to this https://github.com/dkrizman/dash-manufacture-spc-dashboard.

At the beginning a Dataframe is read in from a csv. My problem seems to be quite easy to solve but somehow I am not succeeding:
I want to create a initial window that allows the user to select (from e.g. dropdown) the csv file (or accordingly the path) that is read in. All the .csv files look the same but just have different values.

When using the modal components I get problems with the install of bootstrap and I thought there must be an easier way?

Thanks for your help!
Best,
Nik

Comment: Hey Nik, could you please provide us with more info about the error and perhaps a snippet of the code where you are facing this issue? It's a bit difficult to guide you when we can't see these things, thanks!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.